# How to include / exclude TestNG groups when running test via Gradle

Tags: gradle, testng

I'm trying to create a Gradle Test task that will only run tests belonging to a certain group.

My tests are annotated like this ...

```
@Test(groups = {"chrome"})
public void myTest() {
    //test code lives here...
}
```

My Gradle task is setup like this

```
test {
    useTestNG() {
        excludeGroups 'chrome'
    }
}
```

However when I invoke the tests using

```
./gradlew clean test
```

All the tests tagged as belong to the chrome group are still being run.

I'm using Gradle 1.0 milestone7 on Mac OSX 10.7.3

TestNG 6.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works fine for me. Can you provide a small self-contained build that demonstrates the problem?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, at least I know the syntax is correct for now. I'll put together a small project and share it with you shortly.

Comment: While I'm doing that is there anything special I would need to do to get it working in reverse and only run the tests in the chrome group?          test {
useTestNG() {
    includeGroups 'chrome'
    }
}

Comment: You don't have to do anything special; your code should work as-is.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. I had created a test project and got it working in the process. The key point for getting the tests to run when using excludeGroups was that any methods annotated as '@BeforeSuite, @BeforeMethod', etc needed to have AlwaysRun=true

Comment: [My test project](https://github.com/iainrose/page-objects) incase anyone is interested